# Misunderstanding of percentage increase

Tags: percentages

If something increase $50$ to $200$, I know that it is $400\%$ increment using common sense.

I can get this using $\dfrac{200}{50}\times 100\% =  400\%$.

If something increase $50$ to $52$, I know that it is $4\%$ increment using common sense.

But if I apply the same logic, $\dfrac{52}{50}\times 100\% = 104\%$.

What is the problem in my logic?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that your mistake is very common.  For small increases, the percentage is usually correct.  As the increase gets larger, mistakes become frequent. It is common to confuse $4$ times bigger with $400 \%$ more.  Think about $100 \%$ bigger which means double and not the same.

Comment: @badjohn Yes, Even after doing maths for AL and even after getting "B" grade I am really ashamed of myself.

Comment: Don't be too harsh on yourself, as I said, it is a common mistake.  An interesting question is at what point people tend to switch.  $100 \%$ is usually correctly interpreted as double.  By your example of $400 \%$, the mistake is common.  How is $200 \%$ commonly perceived?

Comment: Note that the other words around the percent number itself make a big difference. $200$ is $400\%$ **of** $50$, but $200$ is a $300\%$ **increase** from $50$, or is $300\%$ **more than** $50$. $52$ is $104\%$ **of** $50$, but $52$ is a $4\%$ **increase** from $50$, or is $4\%$ **more than** $50$. "**Percent more than**" is equal to "**percent of**" minus $100$.

Comment: Related, possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2417020/what-is-the-difference-between-ratio-change-vs-percent-change-finance-questio/2417032#2417032

Comment: I have heard an anecdotal story on percentage increase: There was a debate on "Do law students have to study Mathematics?" The lawyer claimed it was not necessary for them. The mathematician asked him the question: "Last year there were $80$ crimes, this year there were $100$ crimes. How much percentage increase is this?" The lawyer quickly and with confidence replied "$20$ percent"... The moral of the story is the mathematics is necessary for each and every subject and profession.

Comment: If you'll notice, both of the answers that you got (400% and 104%, respectively) are 100 percentage points away from the actual answers (300% and 4%, respectively) when we're talking about *percentage increase*, which involves addition and subtraction. However, when we're talking about *percentage of*, that involves multiplication and division, and you're exactly correct on both counts: 50 * 400% = 50 * 4 = 200, and 50 * 104% = 50 * 1.04 = 52. So you had the right answers, but were calling them the wrong thing.

Comment: @badjohn Arguably, "4 times bigger" should mean "400%". One should say instead "four times *as big*" to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @farruhota I don't understand the anecdote. Someone whose profession is P claims that subject S isn't required in profession P, and makes a mistake in S. How does it show that S actually is needed in P?

Comment: @JiK, the lawyer underestimated (answered $20\%$ instead of $25\%$) and showed his incompetence in math, consequently in law and lost the argument...

Comment: @farruhota I don't see how being incompetent in subject S and losing an argument about subject S shows that subject S is important.

Comment: @JiK, do not worry, I myself do not understand some anecdotes. Cheers.

Comment: Of course this has already been answered but maybe it’s intuitive to write it as 50+x*50=200 => x=(200-50)/50=3 -> in % : 3*100=300% .. What do u think?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Percentage increase is $$\frac{\text{new number - old number}}{\text{old number}}\times 100 \%$$

The right comptuation should be $$\frac{200-50}{50} \times 100 \%=300\%$$

Comment: Maybe to make it more intuitive (I mean to see where it comes from) to write it as an equation: 50+x*50=200 => x=(200-50)/50=3 -> in % : 3*100=300% .. What do u think?

Comment: sure, that helps.

Answer (score 82):

If something increases from $50$ to $200$, it increases **by** $300\%$ and has a new value that is $400\%$ of the old value.

Similarly, if something increases from $50$ to $52$, it increases by $4\%$ to a new value that is $104\%$ of the old one.

Answer (score 13):

The convention is that "percentage increase" is the number of percentage points that are *added.*

So it is assumed that you always start with $100\%$ of a number and then add an $n\%$ percent increase to that, so you end up with $(100 + n)\%$ of the original number.

If you take the *ratio* of the starting and ending amounts and multiply by $100\%,$
you end up with the figure $(100 + n)\%.$ You then have to subtract $100\%$ if what you want is the percentage increase.

Indeed $52$ is $104\%$ of $50,$  but the *added* amount is only $2,$ which is $4\%$ of $50.$
Likewise $200$ is $400\%$ of $50,$ but the *added* amount is only $150,$ which is $300\%$ of $50.$

Answer (score 7):

You are making the classic mistake of confusing ratio with change.

$ratio = \frac{new\;value}{old\;value}$

$percentage\;ratio = \frac{new\;value}{old\;value} \times  100\%$

$difference = new\;value - old\;value$

$percentage\;change = \frac{difference}{old\;value} \times  100\% = \frac{new\;value - old\;value}{old\;value} \times  100\%$

Change is more commonly known as growth or increase.

Answer (score 2):

This is were the ratio makes more sense

That is when

$50:400$

are divided one both sides by $50$ giving us

$1:8$

so my understanding is that it is eight times more.

Comment: 50/400 reduces to 1/8 not 1/4

Comment: Thank you - applied your correction. Peter Paff.

Answer (score 1):

If you see your question, you'll see that you have answered it yourself. In the second statement, you said $50$ to $52$ increment means $4$% which is equal to $100$ subtracted from $104$ which you have calculated. Similarly, if you subtract $100$ from $400$ you will get $300$%.